# Confirm order button does not seems like button its like a written text

Tags: opencart

Confirm order button on the checkout page does not seems like button.
It sees like a written text, How to display it like button.

Any hep??

Comment: use the css to style the button simple.

Answer (score 2):

This is also a button. It depends on checkout payment process, Go to theme template payment folder.Check it here all payment related template is present here,here you can the confirm order button design for all the payments.